# Put two images in one LimeJS layer

Tags: javascript, limejs

I want to put two images within one LimeJS layer. The images should be aligned horizontally next to each other.

Adding one image into a layer is straight forward:

```
var myLayer = new lime.Layer().setPosition(0, 0)

var myImage = new lime.Sprite().setSize(800,400).setFill('myimage.png');

myLayer.appendChild(myImage);   

scene.appendChild(myLayer);
```

But to add two images into one layer doesn't *seem* possible. I have read [LimeJS Docs](http://limejs.digitalfruit.ee/docs/index.html) however my class document reading experience is sketchy.

I have tried using the `setOffset` method on the `Sprite` class:

```
var myLayer = new lime.Layer().setPosition(0, 0);

var myImage = new lime.Sprite().setSize(800,400).setFill('myimage.png');
var myImage2 = new lime.Sprite().setSize(800,400).setFill('myimage.png')
             .setOffset(800, 0, true); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

myLayer.appendChild(myImage);    
myLayer.appendChild(myImage2);    

scene.appendChild(myLayer);
```

But the above returns `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Maybe putting two images into one layer is not possible but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typeError is occurring because the `Sprite` object does not include a `setOffset` method.  That can be found on the `lime.fill.Image` object.

Consider using the `setPosition` method, which `Sprite` inherits from `lime.Node`

Here are the lime docs that relate to it:

[Class Lime Sprite](http://limejs.digitalfruit.ee/docs/symbols/lime.Sprite.html)

Good luck!